# Duality of chain complexes

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an exact category. If $\mathcal{A}^*$ denotes the opposite category of $\mathcal{A}$ and $Ch(\mathcal{A})$ is the category of the chain complexes of $\mathcal{A}$, then is it true that $Ch(\mathcal{A}^*)=(Ch(\mathcal{A}))^*$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an isomorphism of categories, sending a chain complex in $A$ to the cochain complex in $A^*$ with opposite grading and differential. This is unusual: chain complexes are a category of (additive) functors $D\to A$, and generally the opposite of the category $[D,A]$ of functors would be $[D^*,A^*],$ not just $[D,A^*]$. We get lucky here because the domain category $D$ for chain complexes happens to be isomorphic to its own opposite. (It's got objects $\mathbb{Z}$ with homs $D(i,j)$ free of rank 1 if $j=i-1$, and zero otherwise.)